# Xcode. Unable to stop at breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, breakpoints

I have an issue with debugging my iOS application. When the app reaches the breakpoint it stops there for a second and then the debugger crashes. (The app doesn't crash, only the debugger. A behavior similar to a device being disconnected from cable while it's in debug mode).

The print from Xcode Console:

> Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log
>   is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix
>   'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash
>   log.

I checked the crash log and here's the part of the file:

```
Process:               lldb-rpc-server [21320]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDBRPC.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lldb-rpc-server
Identifier:            lldb-rpc-server
Version:               2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Xcode [15500]
Responsible:           lldb-rpc-server [21320]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2018-04-12 17:20:19.901 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        BCD9F4BE-3ECF-2DD0-68EC-671CF1821432


Time Awake Since Boot: 24000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        8  RPC packet thread for client tid 00055ab9 (350905)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Stack dump:
0.  error finding type for _T07Staging11AppDelegateCD
abort() called

Thread 8 Crashed:: RPC packet thread for client tid 00055ab9 (350905)
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff70cdcb6e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70ea7080 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff70c3824d __abort + 144
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff70c381bd abort + 142
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011132acdd swift::ModuleFile::fatal(llvm::Error) + 1213
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000111332711 swift::ModuleFile::getDeclChecked(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>, llvm::Optional<swift::DeclContext*>) + 27649
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000111359e39 swift::ModuleFile::lookupValue(swift::DeclName, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) + 841
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110b43f9a swift::ModuleDecl::lookupValue(llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::DeclName, swift::NLKind, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) const + 90
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110b4e8aa void lookupInModule<llvm::SmallSet<swift::CanType, 4u, (anonymous namespace)::SortCanType>, swift::namelookup::lookupInModule(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::DeclName, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&, swift::NLKind, swift::namelookup::ResolutionKind, swift::LazyResolver*, swift::DeclContext const*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*> >)::$_0>(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&, swift::namelookup::ResolutionKind, bool, swift::LazyResolver*, llvm::SmallDenseMap<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*>, llvm::TinyPtrVector<swift::ValueDecl*>, 32u, llvm::DenseMapInfo<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*> >, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*>, llvm::TinyPtrVector<swift::ValueDecl*> > >&, swift::DeclContext const*, bool, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*> >, swift::namelookup::lookupInModule(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::DeclName, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&, swift::NLKind, swift::namelookup::ResolutionKind, swift::LazyResolver*, swift::DeclContext const*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*> >)::$_0) + 346
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110b4e71e swift::namelookup::lookupInModule(swift::ModuleDecl*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::DeclName, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&, swift::NLKind, swift::namelookup::ResolutionKind, swift::LazyResolver*, swift::DeclContext const*, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >, swift::ModuleDecl*> >) + 1278
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110b550e1 swift::DeclContext::lookupQualified(swift::Type, swift::DeclName, swift::NLOptions, swift::LazyResolver*, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) const + 1089
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c56db2 DeclsLookupSource::lookupQualified(swift::Identifier, swift::NLOptions, swift::LazyResolver*, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ValueDecl*>&) + 226
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c5693d FindFirstNamedDeclWithKind(swift::ASTContext*, llvm::StringRef const&, swift::DeclKind, VisitNodeResult&, llvm::Optional<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >) + 301
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c5608c VisitNodeIdentifier(swift::ASTContext*, swift::Demangle::Node*, swift::Demangle::Node*, VisitNodeResult&) + 124
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c4ebf7 VisitNode(swift::ASTContext*, swift::Demangle::Node*, VisitNodeResult&) + 199
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c4eba0 VisitNode(swift::ASTContext*, swift::Demangle::Node*, VisitNodeResult&) + 112
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c4eba0 VisitNode(swift::ASTContext*, swift::Demangle::Node*, VisitNodeResult&) + 112
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c4eba0 VisitNode(swift::ASTContext*, swift::Demangle::Node*, VisitNodeResult&) + 112
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000110c5475c swift::ide::getTypeFromMangledSymbolname(swift::ASTContext&, llvm::StringRef, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&) + 204
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011172ceda lldb_private::SwiftASTContext::GetTypeFromMangledTypename(char const*, lldb_private::Error&) + 532
20  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001114a5101 DWARFASTParserSwift::ParseTypeFromDWARF(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, DWARFDIE const&, lldb_private::Log*, bool*) + 887
21  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001115c2623 SymbolFileDWARF::ParseType(lldb_private::SymbolContext const&, DWARFDIE const&, bool*) + 171
22  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001115bc33f SymbolFileDWARF::GetTypeForDIE(DWARFDIE const&, bool) + 369
23  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001115bbc6e SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveType(DWARFDIE const&, bool, bool) + 68
24  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001115bbbed SymbolFileDWARF::ResolveTypeUID(unsigned long long) + 45
25  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001116390d7 lldb_private::SymbolFileType::GetType() + 51
26  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011147be4f lldb_private::ValueObjectVariable::GetCompilerTypeImpl() + 21
27  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011146cf67 lldb_private::ValueObject::MaybeCalculateCompleteType() + 39
28  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001114712dd lldb_private::ValueObject::GetObjectRuntimeLanguage() + 33
29  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011147167b lldb_private::ValueObject::IsRuntimeSupportValue() + 73
30  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010eb3faec lldb::SBFrame::GetVariables(lldb::SBVariablesOptions const&) + 624
31  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000010eb3fda4 lldb::SBFrame::GetVariables(bool, bool, bool, bool, lldb::DynamicValueType) + 208
32  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e8b0aef rpc_server::_ZN4lldb7SBFrame12GetVariablesEbbbbNS_16DynamicValueTypeE::HandleRPCCall(rpc_common::Connection&, rpc_common::RPCStream&, rpc_common::RPCStream&) + 219
33  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e87662a rpc_common::Connection::PrivateHandleRPCPacket(rpc_common::RPCPacket&, rpc_common::RPCPacket&, bool&) + 506
34  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e87730c rpc_common::Connection::HandleRPCPacket(rpc_common::RPCPacket&) + 62
35  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e87a862 Packets::ProcessPackets() + 254
36  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e87a68b Packets::ReadThread() + 187
37  lldb-rpc-server                 0x000000010e87a5cb Packets::RunReadThread(void*) + 9
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70ea4661 _pthread_body + 340
39  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70ea450d _pthread_start + 377
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff70ea3bf9 thread_start + 13
```

(the full output could be found here)
https://pastebin.com/18ZE08kv

Line 28 says:

> 1. error finding type for _T07Staging11AppDelegateCD

Does anybody know, what the error means?
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your breakpoint by a line. Clean the project and try to run again, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was helpful even though in some cases it still crashes but at-least i can continue working. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new in stackoverflow and i have less then 15 reputations therefore I can't vote. again Thank you.